# Property of a given entire function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be an entire function and let $\lvert f(z)\rvert \le \lvert z\rvert$, for all complex z.
Show that then $f(z) = \alpha z$ for some constant $\alpha$.

I feel like I need to use the [maximum modulus principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle) here but I'm confused because there is no boundary as $f$ is entire. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply Liouville's theorem to the function $f(z)/z$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{z}$  [(entire function)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity)

Fixed $w\in \mathbb{C}$, let $R>|w|$ and $\displaystyle h(z)=\frac{g(z)-g(0)}{z}$  [(entire function)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity)

$\displaystyle |h(z)|\le \frac{1+|g(0)|}{R}$ for $z\in \partial B(0,R)$ so the maximum modulus  principle implies

$$\displaystyle |h(z)|\le \frac{1+|g(0)|}{R} \text{ for } z\in  B(0,R)$$

Therefore $\displaystyle |h(w)|\le \frac{1+|g(0)|}{R}$ , $R\longrightarrow\infty$ , $h(w)=0$ , $h\equiv0$.